# Notes Addon on Storybookjs with Ember

Tags: ember.js, storybook

Trying to use  notes with storybookjs in ember
I'm unable to get the notes to display

```
export const text = () => ({
  template: hbs`<button {{action onClick}}>Hello Button</button>`,
notes,"Awesome Notes.. The Best Notes",
  context: {
    onClick: action('clicked'),
  },
});
```